# Grakn Install: Java version unsupported

Tags: java, archlinux, vaticle-typedb

One is trying to run Grakn from Arch Linux system. On
`./grakn server start`, one gets the following error message (along with the instruction to check grakn server status or log files, which do not reveal anything).

> Unsupported Java version [14] found. Grakn needs Java 1.8 in order to run.

`java --version` gives the following:

> openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12, mixed mode)

Clearly, the Java version is more updated, and may not be the issue. How can one resolve this? One really wants to use Grakn, but does not wish to install Ubuntu to run that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A workaround is using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), which provides a nice command-line interface for switching between versions of various runtimes, including Java (e.g. AdoptOpenJDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking java versions available on Arch Linux, use
`archlinux-java status`
For changing versions, use
`sudo archlinux-java set <option>`

An example is displayed below:
[image]